# Self advertising and posting a candidate constructive proof

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I would like to learn about appropriateness of posting a candidate constructive proof that decides a conjecture or open question and asking for counter examples that render the proof incorrect.

The motivation for doing so would be to abstain from publication and/or modify the claim about what the proof candidate actually accomplishes.

As I don't see on which side of the border between the nebulous "self advertisement" and the "sharing knowledge" realms of MO such a posting would be seen I would like to hear of arguments in favor or against such posting.

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1265/using-math-overflow-to-check-whether-or-not-a-proof-is-correct?noredirect=1&lq=1 or/and https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3510/is-there-a-clear-rule-against-check-this-proof-type-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think that my question has a bit of a different flavor by asking for counter examples to a constructive proof, which IMHO is not quite the same as asking whether a proof is correct in the sense of identifying the reasoning that is flawed

Comment: I understand this. I think, your question is a special case of what was asked earlier (and, as far as I can tell, decided that it's in general MO-appropriate, subject to the standard caveats). But this was long ago and the current consensus might be different.

Comment: If you can isolate the specific step you are interested in, then I see little issue with asking if there are issues with the constructivity or otherwise of that step.

Comment: I agree with @DavidRoberts, where the bit about isolating a specific step is crucial.